# How to make a picture appear in a cell after pressing a button

Tags: swift, boolean, swiftui

In SwiftUI I have a button in a View:

```
Button(action: {self.isMatrimonioOn.toggle()}) {
    Image(!isMatrimonioOn ? "imageA" : "imageA_color")
}
```

When the user presses the button it changes color (imageA-> imageA_color) and at the same time an image (imageA_Color itself) must appear in the cell in another view. How should I set the function?

---

Thanks but I still haven't succeeded. I put it, I think, but when the button is pressed it does not change the image.

```
 @Binding var isMatrimonioOn : Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("sfondo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 350, height: 180)

            CellBackground()
            .offset(x: 93, y: 29)

                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {             

                    if isNataleOn == true {
                    Image("imageA").offset(x: 3, y: 15)
                    } else {
                        Image("none")
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming "another view" here is a child view of this view and `isMatrimonioOn` is a `@State`*

The child view can have a `var` with attribute `@Binding` to which you can pass `$isMatrimonioOn`.

You can then use logic like in your question or `if` statement wrapping the image.